# Get top-k predictions from tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am relatively new in machine learning especially when it comes to implementing algorithms. I am using python and tensorflow library to implement a neural network to train on a dataset which has about 20 classes. I am able to train and get predictions successfully but I have a question,

> Is it possible to get top k classes along with their probabilities using tensorflow instead of just a single prediction?

If it is possible how can this be done? Thanks for your guidance.

**Update 01:**
I am adding code of what I am doing. So I build a neural network with 3 layers having tanh, sigmoid, & sigmoid respectively as activation functions for the hidden layers and softmax for output layer. The code for training and prediction is as follows:

```
y_pred = None
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):            
            # running the training_epoch numbered epoch
            _,cost = sess.run([optimizer,cost_function],feed_dict={X:tr_features,Y:tr_labels})
            cost_history = np.append(cost_history,cost)
        # predict results based on the trained model
        y_pred = sess.run(tf.argmax(y_,1),feed_dict={X: ts_features})
```

Right now y_pred is a list of class labels for each test example of ts_features. But instead of getting 1 single class label for each test example I am hoping to get top-k predictions for each example each of the k-predictions accompanied by some kind of probability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k):

```python
top_k_values, top_k_indices = tf.nn.top_k(predictions, k=k)
```

If `predictions` is a vector of probabilities per class (i.e. `predictions[i] = prediction probability for class i`), then `top_k_values` will contain the `k` highest probabilities in `predictions`, and `top_k_indices` will contain the indices of these probabilities, i.e. the corresponding classes.

---

Supposing that in your code, `y_` is the vector of predicted probabilities per class:

```
k = 3  # replace with your value
# Instead of `y_pred`:
y_k_probs, y_k_pred = sess.run(
    tf.nn.top_k(y_, k=k), feed_dict={X: ts_features})
```

Comment: Hi Sorry, I don't think I fully follow your answer. I am adding my code to the question of what I am doing. Can you guide me where and how I can get the results with top_k()

Comment: I tried to make my answer more explicit. Hope it helps

Comment: use `tf.nn.top_k` instead of `tf.math.top_k`.